# Break a stick at $n$ random points. What is the probability that the three shortest pieces can form a triangle, as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: probability, limits, triangles, geometric-probability

**Question :**

On a stick, choose $n$ uniformly random points, and break the stick at those points. What is the limit of the probability that the **three shortest pieces** can form a triangle, as $n\to\infty$?

**Context :**

I'm currently interested in questions about broken sticks. They often have [nice answers](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/336_20/papers18/allen.pdf).

**My attempt :**

I don't know how to find the exact probability, so I ran a simulation on Excel. For each of $n=10,n=100,n=1000$, the probability seems to be roughly $0.45$. So it seems that the probability quickly converges... but to what?

Comment: If $X_i$ is the length of the $i$th shortest segment, you want $P(X_1+X_2>X_3).$ Not sure what to do with that, though.

Comment: Simulations on my side suggest that the probability tends to $1/2$.

Comment: Moreover, the expected lengths of the three shortest sticks become effectively $1/n^2$, $2/n^2$, and $3/n^2$ as $n$ increases..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the stick is of length 1 and let  $S_{(1)}< S_{(2)}<\dots<S_{(n)}$ be the lengths of the $n$ pieces ordered by magnitude.

We have (see [4.1](http://blog.thegrandlocus.com/static/misc/Pyke_spacings_1965.pdf))

$$ (S_{(1)}, \dots, S_{(n)})\stackrel{d}{=} (X_{(1)}/T_n, \dots, X_{(n)}/T_n),$$
Where $X_{(i)}$ are the order statistics from i.i.d. Exponential(1) random variables, and $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

In particular,
$$P(S_{(1)}+S_{(2)} > S_{(3)}) = P(X_{(1)}+X_{(2)} > X_{(3)}) =P(X_{(1)} > X_{(3)}-X_{(2)}).$$

However, $nX_{(1)}$ and $(n-2)(X_{(3)} - X_{(2)})$ are [i.i.d.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452890/difference-of-statistics-of-order-of-a-exponential-distribution) Exponential(1), [hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332413/comparing-two-exponential-random-variables)
$$P(X_{(1)} > X_{(3)}-X_{(2)}) = \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-2}} = \frac{n-2}{2n-2}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Earlier , when I saw this Question , I got the Answer $0.5$ but was hesitant to Post it , because the Simulation by OP was getting $0.45$ limit. With user "Jeroen van der Meer" & user "Dstarred" confirming $0.5$ limit , I think I can safely Post my Analysis.

**(1) Shortest 3 Consecutive Pieces :**

Let the Stick be broken & the Pieces arranged by Size.
Take the Shortest 3 Consecutive Pieces $(X,Y,Z)$ where $X \le Y \le Z$.
We want $X+Y \ge Z$
We can scale these ( by Dividing throughout by $Z$ ) to get $(x=X/Z,y=Y/Z,z=Z/Z=1)$

What we now want is :
$x+y \ge 1 \tag{C1}$
where
$x \le y \le 1 \tag{C2}$

[image: STICKS]

[[
**OBSERVATION 1 :** In Case , we have the additional Criteria :
$X+Y+Z = Constant \tag{??C3??}$
then it is equivalent to this [Case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4626092/if-the-wire-of-length-ell-is-cut-into-three-pieces-then-find-the-probability/4626111#4626111) , where Probability is $1/4$ , though that Criteria is not valid here in the limiting Case.
]]

That Shaded Area ( larger triangle ) is satisfying (2) , while that Highlighted Area ( Smaller triangle ) satisfies (1) , hence that will give the necessary Probability $P=0.25/0.5=0.5$ , matching the Simulations.

[[
**OBSERVATION 2 :** Simulation Probability is moving from the Initial Case where we have the additional Criteria (C3) to the limiting Case where that Criteria (C3) is irrelevant. The Simulation is moving from $0.25$ ( $n$ close to $3$ ) to $0.5$ ( $n$ very large ) gradually.
]]

**(2) Some 3 Consecutive Pieces , not necessarily the Shortest , not necessarily the longest :**
Let the Pieces be $P_1,\cdots,P_n$ arranged by Size.
When $(P_1,P_2,P_3)$ can give the triangle , Probability is $P=1/2$.
When $(P_1,P_2,P_3)$ can not give the triangle , it is $(1-P)=1/2$ & we can check $(P_2,P_3,P_4)$ , $(P_3,P_4,P_5)$ , $(P_4,P_5,P_6)$ , $(P_5,P_6,P_7)$ , ETC.
Thus total Probability is $P + P \times (1-P) + P \times (1-P)^2+P \times (1-P)^3\cdots=P/(1-(1-P))=1$
Amazingly , we can guarantee a triangle somewhere among 3 Consecutive Pieces in the limiting Case , no matter what $P$ is !
In other words : (A) If we want acute-angled triangle with some non-Zero Probability , then we can guarantee that among 3 Consecutive Pieces when $n$ is very large. (B) If we want obtuse-angled triangle with some non-Zero Probability , then we can guarantee that among 3 Consecutive Pieces when $n$ is very large. (C) If we want all irrational sides of the triangle with some non-Zero Probability , then we can guarantee that among 3 Consecutive Pieces when $n$ is very large. Necessary Criteria is that $P$ must be non-Zero.

Answer (score 3):

Upon running more simulations, I agree with the comments. The probability tends towards $0.5$, as shown in the result graph below

[[image: <span class=]$n = 100$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3jF0.png)

This simulation consisted of $10000 \cdot 10000$ (nested) iterations for every $n$; $\, 2 \le n \le 100$.

The interesting thing to analyse, is the first $10$ values for $n$; $\, 2 \le n \le 10$.

[[image: <span class=]$n = 10$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVfJ0.png)

This is where the most change occurs in probability, and funnily enough can be near perfectly mapped by the density function $$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\cdot\tan^{-1}{(n - 1)}$$

[image: Desmos analysis]

Observe, it nicely obeys our convergence of $0.5$, as $n \to \infty$. However, I am unsure what other useful information this function gives us, other than the analytic continuation of the experiment over $\mathbb{R}$.